# live html reload with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, web, webpack

sorry for the noob question (I'm still newbie with webpack) I'm interested in live reload my html, that means, everytime than I do a change in my html file my browser must show the latest changes, webpack has a nice feature than works for javascript, is possible use it with html?

just now I'm using this skeleton https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate for develop, yes I'm working with react but also I'm building a few static pages

I know about libs like live.js but I found it not so transparent: this reload my browser and this is empty for a few seconds, instead bracket (for html) and webpack (for js) are almost instantly and you dont feel the browser reload, an alternative like this outside of webpack also would be appreciate, thanks

Comment: You should use webpack-dev-server with hot-loading option it reloads everything. Let me know it you need examples of how to use it.

Comment: thanks for the reply..yes would be nice than you could show me how configure https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate for this, just now I've reload for js/jsx files but not for html, notice than it seems accomplished using node server.js (not sure but based in ths file https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json)..

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching google I finally found the answer.
Just add this config:

```
devServer: {
  before(app, server) {
    const chokidar = require('chokidar');
    chokidar.watch('path/to/my-files/').on('all', function (event, path) {
      server.sockWrite(server.sockets, 'content-changed');
    });
  },
}
```

Found it on a blog here: https://daltontan.com/easiest-way-to-reload-webpack-dev-server-when-other-files-change/30